# iPhone gamecenter submitting highest score?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, game-center

I am using below function to submit score to game center. How to modify below code so that I can send the score only if it is highest than already submitted score? And I dont want to maintain the scores locally. Any help?

```
- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forCategory: (NSString*) category 
{
 GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category] autorelease]; 
 scoreReporter.value = score;
 [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error) 
  {
   [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(scoreReported:) withArg: NULL error: error];
  }];
}
```

Thanks.

**Edit : I just found that it is handled by the game center only... Only the top score will displayed on the gamecenter app.**

Comment: For eg. if i call  [Myclass reportScore:1000 forCategory:@"easymode"]; next time if i call [Myclass reportScore:10 forCategory:@"easymode"]; the submitted score will be 10 not 1000. So how to get previous uploaded score so that i can upload score only if currentscore is greater than previous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the previous score using

```
GKLeaderboard *query = [[GKLeaderBoard alloc] initWithPlayerIDs:[NSArray arrayWithObject:yourPlayerId]];

if (query != nil)

{

    [query loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {

        if (error != nil)

            // handle the error.

        if (scores != nil)

            // process the score information.

        }];

}
```

Get more information on [Apple GameKit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW13)